# ionic 3 ion-datetime could select invalid date

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm currently working on my project in ionic 3.

Whether I'm using the ion date-time function, 
the ion date-time could select the invalid date.

Here's the step : 
Select any value with 31 as a date, eg. select October 31 2017

Click done button of ion-datetime picker

Tap again on ion-datetime

Change month from October to November without touching date or year values

Observe that November 31 2017 gets selected which is an invalid date

here's my ion-datetime html code :

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="meetingDate" min="{{minMeetingDate}}" 
max="{{maxMeetingDate}}" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStartDate()" class="font-card-content">
</ion-datetime>
```

and here's the ngModelChange method :

```
onChangeStartDate() {
    console.log(this.showTimeList);
    if (this.showTimeList) {
      this.showTimeList = false;
      this.showSubmitButton = false;
    }
}
```